# I couldn't enter php variable inside css style tag which I typed in echo line

Tags: php, html, css

I couldn't get expected answer.How to add php variable in style tag which in echo statement

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Grantt chart for given process</h2>
    <divclass="progress">
      <?php $a='80%'; 
             echo '<div class="progress-bar progress bar-success"role="progressbar" style="width: {$a}"  >';
             echo '</div>';?> 
    </div 
</div>
```

I expected bar with 80% filled

Comment: you have some error in your html code. Please check it.

Comment: Please, edit your question. It's hard to understand, what's your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Too little information to actually progress with this. Definitely an error in the PHP code which is breaking the HTML syntax. My guess would be that this is a .HTML file with PHP code inside.

Comment: `<divclass="progress">` Missing a space there. And it's "Gantt chart", not "Grantt chart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using single quotes, the variable is not interpreted in single quotes.
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

you have to use string concatenation or replace your single quotes with doubles and escape the html quotes
`echo '<div class="progress-bar progress bar-success"role="progressbar" style="width: '.$a.'"  >';`

`echo "<div class=\"progress-bar progress bar-success\" role=\"progressbar\" style=\"width: {$a}\"  >";`